# Magento Hole puch With Varnish

Tags: magento, varnish, hole-punching

I recently installed the varnish 3.x in system (ubuntu) and configured it to 8080.

Now full page caching is enabled and its working fine. I just want to ignore some 
specific dynamic blocks of the page. How can i do with magento. Also i am not 
using Magentos default caching techniques so i disabled it. also tried module Terpentine

Thanks & Regard

Rajesh Ganjeer

Comment: question not clear, do you want to turn off cache for particular block or want to disable block?

Comment: Yes i want to  turn off cache for particular block. Please suggest.. it is urgent requirement but not getting any help..

Comment: Are you using an extension to enable Varnish support in Magento or have you just installed Varnish in front of your web server? Disabling Magento's block cache will do nothing as Varnish (by default) will cache any output regardless. To implement hole punching, you need to research Edge Side Includes. These essentially allow you to control the cache policies of page blocks independently. There are a few extensions which implement this correctly.

Comment: Thanks for you people who has taken interest on this topic. I got the solutions for it. I have answered the solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have done this using

Try this in local.xml  inside the app/design/frontend/XXX/XXX/layout/local.xml file:

```
<reference name="block name">
    <action method="setEsiOptions">
        <params>
            <access>private</access>
            <flush_events>
                <wishlist_item_save_after/>
                <wishlist_item_delete_after/>
                <sales_quote_save_after/>
                </flush_events>
        </params>
    </action>
</reference>`
```

**OR**

```
<reference name="block name">
    <action method="setEsiOptions">
        <params>
            <access>private</access>
            <ttl>0</ttl>
        </params>
    </action>
</reference>`
```

**OR**

```
<reference name="block name">
<action method="setEsiOptions">
    <params>
        <access>private</access>
        <method>ajax</method>
    </params>
</action>
</reference>`
```

**OR**

Whole page will ignore cached eg. one page module checkout_onepage_index

```
<checkout_onepage_index>
    <turpentine_cache_flag value="0"/>
</checkout_onepage_index>
```

I tried this using module Nexcessnet Turpentine. and it works

**For your reference after Turpentine installation :**

app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/turpentine_esi.xml

Thanks a lot for your feedbacks.

**Reference Sites :**

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/turpentine-varnish-cache.html

https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine

**Thanks & Regards**

Rajesh Ganjeer

Answer (score 1):

Follow this to start to end solutions for varnish

http://rajeshganjeer.wordpress.com/2014/05/28/varnish-with-magento-terpentine/

Answer (score 0):

Try this in layout.xml file:

```
 <reference name="block name">
      <action method="setCacheLifetime"><s>null</s></action>
  </reference>
```

if you want to disable in phtml file then use false after block name like this:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks',false) ?>
```

and if you want to disable from php file then use this code in specific Block class:

```
public function getCacheLifetime() { return null; }
```

Hope this helps. All the best!

Comment: This affects Magento's block cache only. Varnish cache will not be purged this way.

Answer (score 0):

Using Turpentine will be the way to go.

The specific link you are looking for is to:
https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/wiki/ESI_Cache_Policy

With the detail being:

> The default ttl if not specified is a little complex: If access is
>   private, then if method is ajax the default ttl is 0 (not cached)
>   otherwise the default cookie expiration time is used. If access is
>   global then the default page TTL is used (regardless of method).

Implemented like:

```
<reference name="block name">
    <action method="setEsiOptions">
        <params>
            <access>private</access>
            <ttl>0</ttl>
        </params>
    </action>
</reference>
```