# Magento Varnish Cached blocks visible for logged in users

Tags: magento, caching, varnish, esi

My clients Magento-site is hosted on SiteGround with SuperCacher activated. SuperCacher is a SiteGround optimized version of Varnish.

It uses a version of Turpentine for Varnish caching.

I've got at Search block that is only visible to logged in users.
This block won't show up when Varnish is activated.

When I specify af ESI policy with ttl 0 for the Search block, it becomes visible but for both logged in and logged out users.

How do I leave this block out of the cache and only show up for logged in users?

Answer (score 0):

this link is very useful to me in this link explanation for how to remove block from cache [Magento Hole puch With Varnish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807938/magento-hole-puch-with-varnish) Hope this will also helpful to you.